# Encountered an error while setting up a Python environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, trigger.io

I'm developing a web-browser extension, and have found a tool which will allow me to publish the extension for all browsers from a single code-base. The tool is called [Open Forge](https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions) and is developed by [Trigger.io](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/09/10/introducing-openforge-an-open-source-cross-platform-browser-add-on-framework/).

The setup instructions listed in the Open Forge ReadMe (included in the link above) involve creating and configuring a new python environment. I've been able to create and activate a new python environment in my project directory, however the command to configure the environment (pip install -r requirements.txt) generates the following exception:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 347, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 497, in install
    and req.installed_version in distribute_req):
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2851, in __contains__
    return self.specifier.contains(item, prereleases=True)
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 651, in contains
    item = parse(item)
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 41, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\Users\ian\Documents\Kitchology\browser-extensions\python-env\lib\site
-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 202, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

The process hangs on line 17 of the requirements.txt document. The line in question is:

> PyHamcrest==1.6

I have also attempted this process on Unix (OS X) and encountered the same error.

I'm able to complete the process successfully by specifying the latest version of PyHamcrest (1.8) in requirements.txt. I've never used PyHamcrest before, and don't feel comfortable speculating as to why 1.8 works while 1.6 does not.

Comment: _Update:_ I'm able to complete the process successfully by specifying the latest version of PyHamcrest (1.8) in requirements.txt. I've never used PyHamcrest before, and don't feel comfortable speculating as to why 1.8 works while 1.6 does not. I'd love to get the opinions of a few Py-Gurus!

Comment: Which version of pip is this? I just tried doing this, and was able to install with PyHamcrest==1.6 on OS X.

Comment: @bsravanin it's pip version 6.0.3

Comment: @matsjoyce Thanks for the edit, apologies for the poor formatting